# Is Akshata used in North India?

Tags: culture, customs

It is ubiquitous in the South on religious occasions - is it also used in North India?

For example refer [this](http://www.thespiritualindian.com/why-hindu-bride-pushes-rice-pot/)

The rice doesn't seem to have been covered in turmeric.

Comment: Yes it is used in North India too like it is in South India.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Post it as answer.

Comment: That's just a line. @Sarva

Comment: If that is the answer, then it should be posted if it is a word or a line @TheLittleNaruto Add some link if you feel necessary. That is enough. If I were you, I would just post a yes as an answer. :P

Comment: Alright. @Sarvabhouma

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is used in north India as well.That white rice version only the one you shared in the link.

1. It is used as one of the offerings to deities while doing *Pooja* (Worship).
2. It is also used to make beautiful Alpana designs at the door of the houses.
3. It is used to put as Tilak on forehead as well.

Comment: akshata on forehead?  how does it stay there?

Comment: @sk check this: https://goo.gl/images/VnQhm2

Comment: Interesting.  Is that religious or a fashion statement?

Comment: @SK that's religious.

Comment: @SK mostly religious, but you can use it as fashion as well. No one is going to stop you :)